# configuration approach for simple c# application (event logging)

Tags: c#, configuration

I have a simple c# logging application that writes a logfile and then uploads it to a "server" either via HTTP-POST or based on a Windows shared folder.

What would be the "right" approach to configure the application, to have two version each using a different method of upload?

Should I set a parameter in the app.config or should I compile 2 binaries?

Comment: What is the Question??...Which two versions what what upload.. could you please provide more info...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your app read a configuration file at runtime (app.config, custom xml file) and decide what to do based on that; it's better than compiling multiple versions of the same app.

Also, check out [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) for a more complete logging solution. NLog uses an [xml file](http://nlog-project.org/2010/09/25/deploying-nlog-configuration.html) that is read at runtime; it allows all logging messages to be saved to a file (or multiple files, based on the error level), to the console or to ignore certain errors. Flexibility is a good thing. You don't always have the luxury of being able to recompile an app for only small changes.

Comment: Thanks, should I then add the difference of the paramter to app.config in different installers?

Comment: @Cilvic yes, that would be easier. This solution would also allow you to change the configuration even after deploying your app.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on the projects using your logging application.

If you are already using it in a lot of other projects and can't refactor them. A seperated assembly might be an approach. If you start from scratch, definitly do it by configuration. When I understand you correct you're talking about differnet `Logger` types.

Generally, I'd recommend you not to write your own logging application. Use an existing one, there are really good ones out ([NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/), [EnterpriseLibrary Logging](http://entlib.codeplex.com/)). You don't want to have bugs in your logging framework, so use something that was tested successful in millions of projects and is stable.

If you need different Loggers for them, you can extend these frameworks.